# Canvas versus jQuery for drag-and-drop drawing application

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am designing a very basic, web based, drawing-type application (compatibility with desktops is enough) where my users can drag and drop multiple objects onto a designated area.

The objects have different colors and shapes (only basic geometric shapes such as rectangles, trapezoids, etc.), and the user can resize them or rotate them, then save the design (which just sends the coordinates of the objects to database).

I am learning how to design this from scratch.

**Should I mainly use jQuery or should I use the HTML Canvas element, for the above type of webpage application, and what are the pros and cons?**

I understand that they are both based on Javascript, but I am asking so that I know which specific subset to start my learning with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using a framework like [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/). jQuery is great for DOM manipulation (including drag and drop), but not for image processing (even basic use cases like yours). Canvas is good for the latter, but you'd have to implement the former yourself.

You could try to do both at the same time, but it would be awkward (you'd have to deal with multiple canvases at once, etc). Using a library that already does both will save you a lot of effort.

**Note:** That refers only to the user interface. To send data back and forth to your server, jQuery has functions to simplify [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) calls, with good cross-browser behavior. Other frameworks may have similar utilities too, but jQuery is the one I'm familiar with, so it's what I recommend.

Comment: Thank you. "Implement the former" meaning what exactly? Implement drag and drop?

Comment: Yes. jQuery could help you move DOM elemets around, but if you have shapes drawn into a canvas, it can't help you move those shapes around. The click detection/selection and drag/drop are things you'd have to implement from scratch.

Comment: Got it. Also, I just found some [KineticJS tutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/) including drag and drop, which seems reasonably easy to do.

Comment: So, I'd have to create a drawing area using the Canvas element (or a corresponding library), but then when saving/loading the data to server would have to use jQuery -- is that what you mean?

Comment: That's right. KinectJS makes it simple to serialize your whole scene (or selected shapes) as JSON ([example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-save-stage-as-json-string-with-kineticjs/)), but it stops at that - you'll still need a way to get this info to your server. jQuery's ajax is simple and flexible, and don't require you to learn the whole framework at once before using it.

Comment: That clarifies. However, in the last few minutes, I've also just learned about SVG and [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/). Which do you foresee as easier to work with, on the push-to-database aspect? -- KinectJS + jQuery, or SVG/RaphaelJS (where it appears every object/shape will be a DOM)

Comment: Dunno, never tried RaphaelJS... My personal preference is canvas over SVG, but that's subjective. Just two things to note: 1) AFAIK a SVG object embedded into an HTML page is a separate document, I don't think one can access the other's DOM freely through JavaScript; 2) from the linked docs, it seems RaphaelJS also does not have anything to do with ajax, so you'll still need ways to send your data to server.